# How can i pass some value from access token into IAM policy dynamically? (token from user login using cognito)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I need to use the custom value from token in the IAM Policy so that I can restrict the data user can access.

```
   `{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
      {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
          "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
          "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
          "dynamodb:GetItem",
          "dynamodb:PutItem",
          "dynamodb:Query",
          "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
      ],
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<...>:table/<table-name>"
      ],
      "Condition": {
          "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
              "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                  " //**Need to pass data to here**"
              ]
          }
      }
     }
    ]
   }`
```

How can I do that? I have gone through the AWS IAM Role doc. But didn't specifies how to use external data inside that.

Comment: What data do you want to pass into your IAM policy?

Comment: I want to pass tenant name in order to achieve multi tenancy